# Como acessar uma diretiva através de um controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Alguém sabe dizer se é possivél acessar uma diretiva através de um controller?

A idéia é que meu controller verifique uma flag que está instanciada na diretiva já que ela faz a verificação para mostrar alguns resultados.

Não tenho um código especifico pois quero saber como o angular se comporta quanto a isso, acesso de Controllers a Diretivas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, é possível fazer, através do serviço `$scope`:

Seja sua diretiva:

```
app.directive("foo", function () {
    "use strict";
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: "<div>{{ flag }}</div>",
        scope: {
            flag: "=flag"
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.flag = 1;
        }
    };
});
```

Um outro controller qualquer:

```
app.controller("Controller", [ function () {
    "use strict";
    this.blabla = 2;

    this.click = function () {
        this.blabla += 1;
    };
}]);
```

No seu HTML você pode fazer com que a variável `flag` dentro da diretiva tenha o mesmo valor da variável do controller `blabla` do seguinte modo:

```
<body ng-controller="Controller as ctrlr">
    <foo flag="ctrlr.blabla"></foo>
    <button ng-click="ctrlr.click()">Click!</button>
</body>
```

Tentei montar um Fiddle para mostrar o código executando, mas não consegui.

Neste exemplo dado, as variáveis `blabla` e `flag` possuem sempre o mesmo valor. Ou seja, toda alteração feita em uma, será refletida na otura. Isto é um bind bi-direcional. É possível fazer binds unidirecionais. Sugiro olhar a documentação do serviço `$scope` para maiores detalhes.

[AngularJS Scopes](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)